# Installing R on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, r

I have just updated my device to Ubuntu 22.04 and I wanted to install R following this readme: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html

This worked fine, however, now I get an error when I try to update my packages:

```
~$ sudo apt update

Err:1 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
Get:7 http://apt.insync.io/ubuntu jammy InRelease [5.531 B]
Reading package lists... Done        
W: GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51716619E084DAB9
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/ InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I have tried all repositories in the readme, same result.

Comment: If you're installing on 22.04, the repo should be Jammy: `deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jammy-cran40/`

Comment: The repository shows "Xenial" (=Ubuntu 16.04). So, obviously you followed the wrong instructions. You can Software & Updates > Other... and edit the wrong entry by replacing "xenial" with "jammy".

Comment: Sorry, that was me just trying out all of the options in the readme. The problem persists with jammy, I have updated my post.

Comment: does this  installation guide help https://itslinuxfoss.com/install-r-ubuntu-22-04/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me that you've missed a step in the guide that you've linked. You need to sign the key. The relevant line in that link is

> `wget -qO- https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc`